# Make gives error when it ties to build ```rog-control-center```

Tags: make, ld

I'm running Ubuntu 22.04 LTS. Here are the specs:
[image]

I'm trying to install `asusctl`. I downloaded the files from GitLab and planned to compile and install them using make and make install, but it crashes with the command `make`. It gives me the error:

```bash
   Compiling lgbm-sys v0.0.1
   Compiling lgbm v0.0.1
   Compiling rog-control-center v6.0.0-alpha1 (/tmp/asus/asusctl/rog-control-center)
error: linking with `cc` failed: exit status: 1
  |
  = note: LC_ALL="C" PATH="/home/lesi-nedo/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/bin:/home/lesi-nedo/miniconda3/bin:/home/lesi-nedo/miniconda3/condabin:/home/lesi-nedo/.cargo/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/snap/bin" VSLANG="1033" "cc" "-m64" "/tmp/rustcj0HTlR/symbols.o" "/tmp/asus/asusctl/target/release/deps/rog_control_center-8bb1727bbbae0811.rog_control_center.2a5cd71df87524b-cgu.13.rcgu.o" "-Wl,--as-needed" "-L" "/tmp/asus/asusctl/target/release/deps" "-L" "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu" "-L" "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu" "-L" "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu" "-L" "/tmp/LightGBM" "-L" "/home/lesi-nedo/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib" "-Wl,-Bstatic" "/home/lesi-nedo/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libcompiler_builtins-13fc9d1ed9c7a2bc.rlib" "-Wl,-Bdynamic" "-lusb-1.0" "-lseat" "-lxkbcommon" "-ludev" "-linput" "-lgbm" "-ldl" "-ldl" "-ldl" "-lgcc_s" "-lutil" "-lrt" "-lpthread" "-lm" "-ldl" "-lc" "-Wl,--eh-frame-hdr" "-Wl,-z,noexecstack" "-L" "/home/lesi-nedo/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib" "-o" "/tmp/asus/asusctl/target/release/deps/rog_control_center-8bb1727bbbae0811" "-Wl,--gc-sections" "-pie" "-Wl,-z,relro,-z,now" "-Wl,-O1" "-nodefaultlibs"
  = note: /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -linput: No such file or directory
          /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgbm: No such file or directory
          collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
          

error: could not compile `rog-control-center` (bin "rog-control-center") due to 1 previous error
make: *** [Makefile:141: build] Error 101
```

I've installed `LightGBM` but in vain.
Help pleazeee

Comment: It looks like you don't have all the prerequisite development packages installed on your system - in particular `libinput-dev` and `libgbm-dev`

Comment: Thank you, it worked.

Comment: Yes thank you, I should have read more about the command ```ld``` before writing any posts